# Using methods and objects, but no arrays

Tags: java

I was here earlier before, and got pointed in the right direction. But I couldn't get the offered solution to work. It now mostly works, but i'm stuck on one part, and I'm not sure how to proceed. If anyone can point me to the right direction, i'll be grateful. I just need a hint, or pointers to something I'm not seeing.
I'm trying to add a random number of days, and determine what that adds up to. I know I have to have a counter that flips over after 7, but I've tried everything, and keep getting errors

```
import java.util.*;
public class pooped
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int day;
        System.out.println(" Days of the week are numbered 1-7"+
                    "From Sunday to Saturday, enter a number now");
        day = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println(isWeek(day));
        printday(day);
    }

    public static boolean isWeek(int day)
    {
        return day >= 0 && day <= 7;
    }

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void addDay()
    {
        int date;
        System.out.println("Enter how many days you want to go forward.");
        date = console.nextInt();

        if (int date > 0)
        {
            int day = date + 1;
        }
    }

    public static void printday(int day) 
    {
        switch (day) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Sunday");
        break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Monday");
        break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("Tuesday");
        break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("Wednesday");
        break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println("Thursday");
        break;

        case 6:
            System.out.println("Friday");
        break;

        case 7:
            System.out.println("Saturday");

        default:
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: I'm trying to add a random number of days, and determine what that adds up to. I know I have to have a counter that flips over after 7, but I've tried everything, and keep getting errors.

Comment: @ReinFowler what's not working?

Comment: @ReinFowler you declared `console` twice

Comment: You arent calling addDay() method in main class

Comment: This looks strange: `return day >= 0 && day <= 7`.  If your day-of-the-week numbers run from 0 to 6 then that should be `day < 7`; if they run from 1 to 7 then it should be `day > 0`.

Comment: I think you should read some beginner tutorial. Putting together random code and then ask for next step on SO isnt best approach

Comment: why have you written `static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);` 2 times?

Comment: @ReinFowler your `addDay()` method isn't changing the day it is changing a local `day` variable you probably want to accept an `int` as a parameter and return an `int` as the result instead of `void` it might look like this `public static int addDay(int day){//code return day;}` then call like this in your main method: `day = addDay(day); printday(day);`

Comment: @brso05 Thanks for that. I'm in a self teaching class, and the book didnt explain that very clearly. Though now I get illegal start of expression when I run it, int date = date + day says is an illegal statement, or a class is expected. What am I doing wrong on that part?

Comment: Fixed that. Thanks guys...Figured it out

Comment: @ReinFowler no problem man glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

If you need

> a counter that flips over after 7

consider using `day = day % 7;` in your main method, which gives you the *modulo* operation.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I have to have a counter that flips over after 7", do you mean that 7 should roll back to 0, 8 to 1, etc?
If that's the case, you need to look at the modulus operator (%)

You inWeek function looks incorrect. If your day is 0 based, it should be:

```
public static boolean isWeek(int day)
{
    return day >= 0 && day < 7;
}
```

Otherwise you will have 8 days.